# How to access sub index values in an array list

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

Preface : I am trying to get customer data using a webservice. I am having issues with storing the data into an array. Where this array will be passed to a text writer method.

Issue:
I am adding values into an Array List from an array. Every iteration is adding 1000 values into the list Array List as per index. 
1st Iteration : arraylist -index 0 will have 1000 values.
2nd Iteration : arraylist -index 1 will have 1000 values.
like this i will have until arraylist -index 7.

[array list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPaNa.png)

Now my question is that I want to store all the 7000 values into an array.

I tried accessing the sub index of the list also tried to save all 7000 records in an array but , even if I declare array size as 7000 , it is only saving 1000 values at once and in the next iteration replacing second iteration values in the first set of values. Reason for seeking only 1000 records is that my web service gives only 1000 records in one request. So I am saving every iteration values into an array List and stuck with this issue.

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5jp.png)

If I can save all the records into an array , I can pass the array to text writer and the issue will be solved.

```cs
public static void GetCustomerData(string _url)
{
    string todaysDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd");
    MyWebServices.Service obj = new MyWebServices.Service();

    obj.Url = _url;

    BlockRange bckr = new BlockRange();

    bckr.lorecord = 1;
    bckr.hirecord = 1000;

    RecordRange rcdr = new RecordRange();
    CustomerElement cust = new CustomerElement();
    List<CustomerElement cus = new List<CustomerElement();
    int finalrcdr = 50000;
    int hrecord = 0;
    int lrecord = 0;

    lrecord = Convert.ToInt32(bckr.lorecord);
    hrecord = Convert.ToInt32(bckr.hirecord);

    Array arr = new Array[finalrcdr];
    Array brr = new Array[finalrcdr];
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    int a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (finalrcdr/ increment); i++)
    {        
        if ((hrecord <= finalrcdr) == true)
        {
            if (((lrecord < hrecord) && lrecord  0) && ((hrecord  lrecord) && hrecord  0))
            {
                bckr.lorecord = lrecord;
                bckr.hirecord = hrecord;

                cus = obj.getcustomerDetails(bckr).ToList();
                arr = cus.ToArray();
                list.Add(arr);

                Array tarr = new Array[finalrcdr];
            }

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(CustomerFilePath + todaysDate + "_" + cus.Count + "." + member_ID, true);

            WriteCustomers(arr, tw);

            lrecord = hrecord+1;
            hrecord = lrecord + 999;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral I tried doing that since past hour and editor is giving me same issue. So i also added a screen capture as well and also the code snippet. Both are unreadable ?

Comment: hrmm, so you are unable to add and remove spaces from this post?

Comment: While you are [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57549838/edit) please also take the time to create a **good [mcve]**. Whatever problem you're having, it can't possible involve the actual "customer data" and whatnot above; you could just as easily construct a code example that just uses code-generated data. And of course, the above code example isn't _complete_ either. See also [ask] for information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: @TheGeneral Tried that, Hoping it got better?. Please let me know if is not readable. I will try posting again.